# pip での grep の使い方

Tags: python, pip, grep

`pip freeze` を実行すると、結果の中に

```
　grep==0.3.2
```

が出てきます。しかし、

`python -m pip freeze | grep パッケージ名`

という風に実際に使おうとすると、

```
'grep' は、内部コマンドまたは外部コマンド、
　操作可能なプログラムまたはバッチ ファイルとして認識されていません。
```

と言われてしまいます。また、listを使った

```
　pip list | grep パッケージ名
```

でも、上記同様使えないと言われてしまいます。

何かやらなければいけない設定などあるのでしょうか？

宜しくお願いします。

Comment: 「python -m pip freeze | grep パッケージ名」というのは、どこで入力しているのですか？

Answer (score 2):

それは`Python`のモジュールとしての`grep`と、`Windows`のコマンドとしての`grep`を混同しています。

`python -m pip freeze | grep パッケージ名`とした時の`grep`は、`grep.exe`とか`grep.bat`等がカレントフォルダや`PATH`で指定したフォルダのどこかに存在している必要があります。

この場合、簡単なのは`grep`の代りに`find`にして、`パッケージ名`を`""`で囲むことですね。
`grep`の仕様やオプションの細かい動作にこだわらないのであれば、同等に見做せる結果を得ることが出来るでしょう。

こんな感じになります。
`python -m pip freeze | find "パッケージ名"`
`pip list | find "パッケージ名"`

---

特定のモジュール/パッケージがインストール済みか/版数は何か調べるなら、`show`コマンドが良さそうです。インストールされていれば依存関係とか詳しい情報も出てきます。

`pip show パッケージ名`

Comment: ＞それはPythonのモジュールとしてのgrepと、Windowsのコマンドとしてのgrepを混同しています。

ありがとうございます。どうやらそうだったみたいです。findを試したらできました。

Answer (score 1):

エラーメッセージから察するに Windows 上で利用されているものと思いますが、`grep` は主に Linux で利用されるコマンドであり、Windows では使用できません。

pip でパッケージの検索をしたいのであれば、[`pip search`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_search/) を試してみてください。

```
$ pip search KEYWORD
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。
windowsにインストールした、Anaconda Prompt(anaconda3)を使っています。